# python 3.+, create a new categorical column based on average price from a pivot_table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

In my table, I have two columns: **Item_Identifier** and **Sales** (actually, there are 20 columns in the table, but others columns don't need to be considered in this case). I want to create a column in the table that divide the sales price into three categories: low, medium and high.

The initial table looks like this:

```
   Item_Identifier   Sales
     Milk             500
     Milk             1200
     Milk             2000
     Beef             60
     Beef             6000
     Tea              150
     Tea              100
     Tea              200
     .                 .
     .                 .
     .                 .
```

The final table I want:

```
   Item_Identifier   Sales     Categories
     Milk             500         medium
     Milk             1200        medium
     Milk             2000        medium
     Beef             60          high
     Beef             6000        high
     Tea              150         low         
     Tea              100         low 
     Tea              200         low
     .                 .
     .                 .
     .                 .
```

**Because the same Item_Identifier can have different sale price**, I use pivot_table to get the average price for each item. And I want to identify the three categories(low, medium and high) by the item_sale_avg.

My pivot_table code likes this:

```
item_sale_avg=combine.pivot_table(values='Sales',index='Item_Identifier')
```

I attempt to use the code below to solve the problem, but it not really gives the result I want:

```
def price_category(data,id_col,new_col,price_pivot_table):
    data[new_col]=''
    i=-1
    for item in data[id_col]:
       i+=1
       if price_pivot_table[item]>500:
          data.loc[i,new_col]='low'
       elif price_pivot_table[item]>=500 or price_pivot_table[item]<1500:
          data.loc[i,new_col]='medium'
       else:
          data.loc[i,new_col]='high'
```

And I realize that even the code above works, it runs pretty slow. Please feel free to give me an idea. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
item_sale_avg = pd.DataFrame({'Sales':[100,500,600,1500,2000]})

print (item_sale_avg)
   Sales
0    100
1    500
2    600
3   1500
4   2000

bins = [-np.inf,500, 1500, np.inf]
labels=['low','medium','high']
item_sale_avg['Price Category'] = pd.cut(item_sale_avg['Sales'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
print (item_sale_avg)
   Sales Price Category
0    100            low
1    500            low
2    600         medium
3   1500         medium
4   2000           high

#bins not include the rightmost edge - parameter right=False
item_sale_avg['Price Category'] = pd.cut(item_sale_avg['Sales'],
                                         bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)
print (item_sale_avg)
   Sales Price Category
0    100            low
1    500         medium
2    600         medium
3   1500           high
4   2000           high
```

Another less flexible solution with [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
item_sale_avg['Price Category'] = np.where(item_sale_avg.Sales <= 500, 'low', 
                                  np.where(item_sale_avg.Sales >= 1500, 'high', 'medium'))

print (item_sale_avg)
   Sales Price Category
0    100            low
1    500            low
2    600         medium
3   1500           high
4   2000           high
```

---

```
item_sale_avg['Price Category'] = np.where(item_sale_avg.Sales < 500, 'low', 
                                  np.where(item_sale_avg.Sales >= 1500, 'high', 'medium'))

print (item_sale_avg)
0    100            low
1    500         medium
2    600         medium
3   1500           high
4   2000           high
```

**Timings**:

```
item_sale_avg = pd.DataFrame({'Sales':[100,500,600,1500,2000]})

print (item_sale_avg)
item_sale_avg = pd.concat([item_sale_avg]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [19]: %timeit item_sale_avg['Price Category'] = np.where(item_sale_avg.Sales < 500, 'low',  np.where(item_sale_avg.Sales >= 1500, 'high', 'medium'))
10 loops, best of 3: 70.4 ms per loop

#ResMar solution
In [20]: %timeit item_sale_avg['Price Category1'] = item_sale_avg['Sales'].map(lambda price: 'low' if price < 500 else 'medium' if price < 1500 else 'high')
10 loops, best of 3: 125 ms per loop

In [21]: %timeit item_sale_avg['Price Category2'] = pd.cut(item_sale_avg['Sales'], bins=[-np.inf,500, 1500, np.inf], labels=['low','medium','high'], right=False)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.17 ms per loop
```

EDIT:

You need first [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict` created from `pivot_table` or `groupby` with `mean` (faster is `groupby` as `pivot_table`):

```
d = df.groupby('Item_Identifier')['Sales'].mean().to_dict()
print (d)
{'Beef': 3030.0, 'Milk': 1233.3333333333333, 'Tea': 150.0}

print (df['Item_Identifier'].map(d))
0    1233.333333
1    1233.333333
2    1233.333333
3    3030.000000
4    3030.000000
5     150.000000
6     150.000000
7     150.000000
Name: Item_Identifier, dtype: float64

bins = [df['Sales'].min(),500, 1500, df['Sales].max()]
labels=['low','medium','high']
df['Price Category'] = pd.cut(df['Item_Identifier'].map(d), bins=bins, labels=labels)
print (df)
  Item_Identifier  Sales Price Category
0            Milk    500         medium
1            Milk   1200         medium
2            Milk   2000         medium
3            Beef     60           high
4            Beef   6000           high
5             Tea    150            low
6             Tea    100            low
7             Tea    200            low
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. However, I want to create the new column by looking at the average price from the pivot_table. And item_sale_avg is the name of the pivot_table.

Comment: Please check modified solution.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I should have known using **cut**. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This code is running slow because you're doing serial `loc` operations and iterating through the `DataFrame`, which is discouraged because it results in a large number of copies being made along the way.

The fast code path is to use `map`. I can't tell what you're doing because you didn't show what you're running the `price_category` on, but I think you want something like this:

```
price_categories = item_sale_avg['Sales'].map(
    lambda price: 'low' if price < 500 else 'medium' if price < 1500 else 'high'
)
```

Then to assign the result to your original dataset (`pandas` should handle aligning the indices for you):

```
data['Price Category'] = price_categories
```